# terminal issue dotenv: source '.env' file in the directory?

Tags: 18.04, terminator

When I open a terminal or change directory this message appears on my terminal. I am using ubuntu 18.04

[image]

have any solutions?

Comment: It sounds like you are using `zsh` / `ohmyzsh` and have enabled the [dotenv plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/dotenv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this to disable the confirmation:

```
echo "ZSH_DOTENV_PROMPT=false" | tee -a ~/.zshrc
```

`zsh` will now load `.env` from the current directory without asking for confirmation.

If you don't need the `dotenv` plugin at all you can disable it like this:

```
sed -r 's/^(plugins=)(.*)dotenv(.*)$/\1\2\3/p' -i ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

you may go to `/.zshrc` remove the plugin
inside the file find the plugin text, it should be something like this.
`plugins=( git,dotenv )`

remove `dotenv` and run `source ~/.zshrc`, it should not be asking again.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put `ZSH_DOTENV_PROMPT=false` on the beginning of `.zshrc` to make it work.